# JQuery AJAX CORs error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a website that takes a GET request and returns a JSON. I can send the website a request using a node server and receive the correct response. However, when I try to send it using client-side javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<myurl>',
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function() { alert("Success"); },
    error: function() { alert('Failed!'); }
});
```

I get the error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load <myurl>. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is
therefore not allowed access.
```

When I try changing the datatype to jsonp by adding `dataType: 'jsonp',` to the ajax request, I get the error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

The chrome developer console tells me the error is coming from the script `<myurl>&callback=jQuery21309685717469546944_1423379667604&_=1423379667605`, and when I open the script I find the JSON response I am trying to retrieve! but I guess somehow it's being interpreted as a javascript function. Any way to resolve this? I have read many SO answers and tried many approaches to no avail.

Comment: My guess is the reason you are getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` is because jQuery is requesting `JSONP`, but you are getting `JSON` back.  I won't be able to tell you much else unless you link the URL you are GETting from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change something server-side to make this work from a browser.  The server will need to either support JSONP or CORS in order to access it cross domain.

You cannot make client-only changes to make JSONP or CORS work - the server must cooperate.

With CORS, the right headers must exist on the http requests between client and server in order to permit the browser to process the cross origin request.

With JSONP, it is a completely different type of response from the server that makes JSONP work (data wrapped in a javascript script) so the server has to produce this other type of response in order for JSONP to work.

---

If you think your server already supports cross origin requests via CORS, then there is probably an error in the implementation somewhere.

---

The cross origin restrictions are implemented inside the browser in order to protect users using the browser.  Such restrictions are not enforced by a server so servers are not limited to which origins they can connect to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had a suspicion it was out of my control. But how come I was able to send a working response using a node server? can a client not replicate the same exact request?

Comment: @woojoo666 - it is the browser itself that enforces cross origin limitations (to protect end-users using the browser).  A server is under no such cross origin limitations.

Comment: oh huh, I had a very limited knowledge about CORs, so thanks so much for clearing things up!!